# Save the result set of a query against a view to a table using the java client library

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

Recently, one of our clients reported not being able to create a table based on a query against a view. That said, they were able to save the result of a query against a table into another table. This issue spawned a more implementation focused question using the Java client libraries. Specifically, is there any way to save the result set of a query against a view to a table using the Java client library? I will be digging and post anything that I find. That said, any early guidance would be appreciated!

To be specific and add more context, I note that  the the following process failed when the query was run against a union view.

```
java -jar BigQueryToCloudExporter.jar ./GAFastAccessKey.p12 '' "

Select date(date_add('2014-08-09',floor(datediff(date(sec_to_timestamp(visitstarttime)),'2014-08-03')/7)*7,"DAY")) WeekEndDate

, hits.eventinfo.eventaction GA_RentalNo

, count(distinct visitID) PDP_PPC

FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([Union_View.GA],

TIMESTAMP('2014-08-30'),

TIMESTAMP('2014-09-13')))

where hits.eventinfo.eventcategory='property attributes'

and brandId=121

--hits.eventinfo.eventcategory='property inquiry'

and trafficsource.medium like '%cpc%'

--and trafficsource.campaign not like '%ppb%'

and trafficsource.campaign like '%mpm%'

group each by WeekEndDate, GA_XXXXXX

order by WeekEndDate, GA_XXXXXX limit 100" StagingQueryTable QueryTable AVRO gs://XXXXXX/QueryTable*.avro
```

On the other hand, the following process succeeded when the query was made against a BigQuery table (keeping everything else same).

```
java -jar BigQueryToCloudExporter.jar ./GAFastAccessKey.p12 '' "

Select date(date_add('2014-08-09',floor(datediff(date(sec_to_timestamp(visitstarttime)),'2014-08-03')/7)*7,"DAY")) WeekEndDate

, hits.eventinfo.eventaction GA_XXXXXX

, count(distinct visitID) PDP_PPC

FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([XXXXXX.ga_sessions_],

TIMESTAMP('2014-08-30'),

TIMESTAMP('2014-09-13')))

where hits.eventinfo.eventcategory='property attributes'

and brandId=121

--hits.eventinfo.eventcategory='property inquiry'

and trafficsource.medium like '%cpc%'

--and trafficsource.campaign not like '%ppb%'

and trafficsource.campaign like '%mpm%'

group each by WeekEndDate, GA_RentalNo

order by WeekEndDate, GA_XXXXXX limit 100" StagingQueryTable QueryTable AVRO gs://XXXXXX/QueryTable*.avro
```

Comment: I don't see any reason why this wouldn't work. By 'save the result set', I take it that you mean extract the results to AVRO in Google Cloud Storage?  What is the error that you are getting? Do you have job ids for the failures?

Comment: Great question Jordan! Let me get this and get back to you.

Comment: I'm with Jordan on this.... there should be no reason for it to fail.  You getting any error of any kind?